# Carrier wave without s3 storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am using carrier wave for image uploads and for testing purposes I don't want to use s3 storage.

This is the carrierwave.rb file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0666
  config.directory_permissions = 0777
  config.fog_directory = 'xxx-development'
  config.storage = :file
  config.enable_processing = false
end
```

And in the ImageUploader class I have

```
storage :file

def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

version :thumb do
  process resize_to_fill: [300, 300]
end
```

And when I push to heroku I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Fog provider can't be blank, Fog directory can't be blank
```

What is it I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Not sure what are you but if you dont want s3 and want the file to upload to the server instead why are you mentioning  `config.fog_directory`  and also what is the storage options provided inside the `uploader` file

Comment: @Viren edited the question please check

Answer (score 1):

If you want it conditional, perhaps set an environment condition on the fog_directory?

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0666
  config.directory_permissions = 0777
  config.fog_directory = 'xxx-development' unless Rails.env.development?
  config.storage = :file
  config.enable_processing = false
end
```

Comment: it works well on development, but gives error on production. Any other reason other than this?

Comment: Ah come to think of it, the way you have the uploader setup, it probably is still expecting a fog storage for production. So you probably need to add an environment check in your uploader as well.